# SQL joining to the same column id

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL query I just get to work out right.  I've put together a test database like this;

```
TABLE MAIN
id name groupone grouptwo
1  Fred 1        3
2  bob  2        1

TABLE DETAIL
id group groupname
1  1     onegrp
2  2     twogrp
4  3     threegrp
```

My Select query is;

```
SELECT name, groupone, grouptwo, groupname
FROM main
INNER JOIN detail
ON main.groupone = detail.group
WHERE main.id = 1
```

The result I get is;

```
id name groupone grouptwo groupname
1  fred  1         3      onegrp
```

How do I change this to instead of giving the result as 1 and 3.
I get  ... fred onegrp, threegrp

I've tried a dozen things but can't get it to work, I sort of want a give me the groupname again option but not sure what the syntax is for that! :(

Thanks in advance for your time and help

Comment: Can you please print the desired output?

Comment: Why would group ID of 3 bring back TwoGroup?

Comment: Sorry just tidied up my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.   You need to join the detail table twice, on the two different keys.

```
SELECT
   m.Name
  ,a.groupname as 'GroupOne'
  ,b.groupname as 'GroupTwo'
FROM
  main m
INNER JOIN
  detail a
     on m.groupone = a.group
INNER JOIN
  detail b
     on m.grouptwo = b.group
WHERE
  m.id = 1
```